# Javascript: Storing and Sorting Data with Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am a beginner and I need help with this programming assignment.

Need to do a prompt. Get 10 names as input from user (string inputs). Put the names into an array and then write it out to the webpage.

My question is how do I save the input in the array, when the prompt has to be displayed over and over again for each name the user enters a name? Also, depending on how many names the user wants to enter, the user has a choice of quitting the prompt by typing in the letter 'q'. I am quite proficient at coding while and for loops, but not so much at coding arrays. Tried to search online but couldn't find an answer.

I would love if somebody could explain how to do it. Thanks!

Comment: You should post your code for what you have attempted so far.  Also, are you allowed to use frameworks?  If so, you should be able to find many examples of an app that does something similar to this that uses jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following solution:

```js
// Create new array with 10 default values:
var result = new Array(10).fill('');

// Fill array with names via prompt():
eval(((a, b = ['x => x' + '.' + '\n' + 'so\x6De']) => b + '\x28' + a + '\x29')((a, b) => 'q' == (x[b] = prompt())))(result);

// Print result:
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

How about something like this?

```
in your html somewhere
<div id="names">

</div>

function getNames(num) {
    var arr = [],
        person,
        max = num || 5; // number of names you want

    return (function R() {
      if (arr.length < max) {
         person = prompt("Please enter your name");
         arr.push(person)
         R()
      } else {
        document.getElementById("names").innerHTML =
        "Hello " + arr.join(", ") + "! How are you today?";
      }
    }())
}

getNames(4)
```

Comment: You are prompting for a name one extra time. On a last iteration the `person` variable is not used.

Comment: cool. I was thinking you did :-). Anyways, I updated it. Not the most succinct version, but thought to lend a hand to the OP. thanks again. (( next time I'll test before I post :-) )

Comment: Why both your implementations stick to recursion? Why not just use loops. Apparently OP solves some beginners tasks and loops is what I believe they expect to see as a solution